# How to find if a line intersects itself in JTS?

Tags: java, geometry, computational-geometry, jts

Is there any way to find out if a LineString intersects itself in JTS? Like in the following image how can i find if the line intersects itself? I am creating that line by just giving coordinates of its 4 edges.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No line can intersect itself.  You don't have "a line"; you have four lines.  You want to see if two of them intersect each other.

You can either calculate the intersection explicitly or look at how the coordinates are labeled.  If you start in the lower right and number the points as A, B, C, and D by going counterclockwise, you can see that you have an intersection if there are lines connect AC and BD.  If they connect AB, BC, CD, and DA there's no intersection possible except at the common points.

Comment: and what about polygon or LinearRing? If i will create a polygon instead of LineString then do i have to do the same thing or is there any simple function which returns true or false for that?

Comment: Not as simple; I only answered the case you posted.  But it's the same idea - if the polygon has a simple connectivity - node i connects to (i+1) - then there's no intersection.  If you have several that aren't simple, I can see where there's an intersection.

Answer (score 3):

If a LineString intersects like that, `isSimple()` will return `false` as self-intersection is not allowed for Simple Geometries.